# HTML/CSS Creating expandable field

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create the following using angular 1.5 and bootstrap:
[image]

1. The blue box will expand/retract whenit is clicked.
2. The red, yellow, brown box contains their own paragraph of text.
3. When the blue box is retracted, it will show the length of the text up to the width of the the containing box (yellow, brown, and red box)
4. When the blue box is expanded, it will show the full text in the red, yellow, brownbox. The max-height of blue box = the tallest red/yellow/brown box that is required to show full text

Can someone please suggest a way to build this design. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want: I use hover not click.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blue {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.red {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}

.green {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.blue:hover {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blue:hover .green {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  float:none;
}

.blue:hover .red {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
<div class="green">Stack Overflow is a community of 4.7 million programmers, just like you, helping each other.</div>
<div class="red">Join them; it only takes a minute:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The overall concept is there. Rather than using hover, is it possible to use click instead?

Comment: You can do that using Javascript. `addEventListener('click')` then change the style of the target element.